# Using JScrollpane with the drawline() method

Tags: java, jscrollpane, graphics2d

If the drawline() method does not add components, how can I display lines hidden off the side of the page with a JScrollpane?

Comment: are you wondering How to use JScrollPane? --- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JScrollPane` use the component's `getPreferredSize` result to make determinations about how large the component is and if it needs to show the scroll bars or not.

Start by overriding the component's `getPreferredSize` method and return an appropriate size which meets the component's current needs

I would recommend having a look at [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: MadProgrammer you are the man! accepting in 7 minutes, when my father "stackoverflow" allows...